# What is the maximum frequency can a bucket of water could make?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics

Does it depend on

1. surface tension?
2. quantity of water?
3. air pressure?

Can you please help me to have solution for these questions?

Comment: You can drive it at almost any frequency. Is there something driving these oscilations in this question.

Answer (score 2):

Wave equations for water are complicated. the boundary conditions have to be taken into account , a lot of [complicated mathematical](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.06242) theory enters.

Only estimates can be made for the highest frequency, and those will depend on the energy needed to break the H2O molecular bonds which make water "water".This is actually researched for [energy needs.](http://www.rexresearch.com/davidsonhho/davidsonhho.html) The frequencies seem to be of the order of radio frequencies, up to 10^12 Herz. So the bucket sets  no bound for induced upper frequencies, it is the molecular structure that sets the limits.